# Loading bulk records from XML into SQL Server 2008 in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement of loading 1000's of records from an XML file into SQL Server 2008. So far by browsing and all I were able to get some code which doesn't work at all. Can anyone please help me out?

I tried searching a lot for the same but could not fix the issue. Is there anything simple and easier to **understand** to achieve the same.

Here is something I have...

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Server.MapPath(filename);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml(path);
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=SAMPLESERVICE;User ID=sa;Password=123");
                    SqlBulkCopy sb = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
                    sb.DestinationTableName = "Customer";
                    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactNo", "ContactNo");
                    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("Address", "Address");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var msg = ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Can anyone correct me if I am wrong somewhere? Any help? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work at all". An exception message and / or stacktrace might help

Comment: Thanks for your time @ste-fu as you can see the above code I have taken things between try and catch block it isn't coming in the catch block so no exception and I can't find any record being added in the database.

Comment: At some point you need to have your `SqlBulkCopy` object call method `WriteToServer()` -- could you try adding `sb.WriteToServer( ds );` as the last line in the `try {}` block.